# Explain uses of these common env variables: HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, & NO_PROXY?

Tags: http-proxy

Can someone explain the purpose and effective usage of these three environment variables?

Is there a common convention when using them?

What happens if I set all of them at the same time? Is this application specific (I assume it is, but are there best practices?).

I see this as a pretty good "long form" answer. I don't know much about these variables or where to find more information about them and would love more information.

Answer (score 1):

These environment variables are used by some tools like wget.

From the wget documentation of [proxies](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html)

```
http_proxy
https_proxy

    If set, the http_proxy and https_proxy variables should contain the URLs of the proxies for HTTP and HTTPS connections respectively.

no_proxy

    This variable should contain a comma-separated list of domain extensions proxy should not be used for. For instance, if the value of no_proxy is ‘.mit.edu’, proxy will not be used to retrieve documents from MIT.
```

But others tools use different configuration of proxy settings, for instrance `curl` use [-x, --proxy](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x) and --no-proxy arguments :

```
 -x, --proxy <[protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]>
 --noproxy <no-proxy-list>
```